# Computing most recent smaller value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with dates (sorted) in one column and values in another. Ex:

```
1/1/2019     10
1/2/2019     12
1/3/2019     8
1/4/2019     20
1/10/2019    8
1/12/2019    22
```

I want to compute in a third column, the most recent date such that value was less than or equal to the current value (if the current is the lowest, then use the current date).  So, for the sample data above,

```
1/1/2019     10    1/1/2019
1/2/2019     12    1/1/2019
1/3/2019     8     1/3/2019
1/4/2019     20    1/3/2019
1/10/2019    8     1/3/2019
1/12/2019    22    1/10/2019
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this without VBA macros?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way.  Paste these in and copy down the column.

```
Column C:  =IF(COUNTIF(B2:B6,D1)=0,A1,MINIFS(A2:A6,B2:B6,D1))

Column D:  =CONCATENATE("<",TEXT(VALUE(B1),"#"))
```

You can hide column D to make it prettier.  It's the criteria being used by the COUNTIF and MINIFS.  Column C is the output.

```
1/1/2019    10  1/3/2019    <10
1/2/2019    12  1/3/2019    <12
1/3/2019    8   1/3/2019    <8
1/4/2019    20  1/10/2019   <20
1/10/2019   8   1/10/2019   <8
1/12/2019   22  1/12/2019   <22
```

Formula view:

```
43466   10  =IF(COUNTIF(B2:B6,D1)=0,A1,MINIFS(A2:A6,B2:B6,D1))  =CONCATENATE("<",TEXT(VALUE(B1),"#"))
43467   12  =IF(COUNTIF(B3:B7,D2)=0,A2,MINIFS(A3:A7,B3:B7,D2))  =CONCATENATE("<",TEXT(VALUE(B2),"#"))
43468   8   =IF(COUNTIF(B4:B8,D3)=0,A3,MINIFS(A4:A8,B4:B8,D3))  =CONCATENATE("<",TEXT(VALUE(B3),"#"))
43469   20  =IF(COUNTIF(B5:B9,D4)=0,A4,MINIFS(A5:A9,B5:B9,D4))  =CONCATENATE("<",TEXT(VALUE(B4),"#"))
43475   8   =IF(COUNTIF(B6:B10,D5)=0,A5,MINIFS(A6:A10,B6:B10,D5))   =CONCATENATE("<",TEXT(VALUE(B5),"#"))
43477   22  =IF(COUNTIF(B7:B11,D6)=0,A6,MINIFS(A7:A11,B7:B11,D6))   =CONCATENATE("<",TEXT(VALUE(B6),"#"))
```

This is a little sloppy in that you could use a named value or absolute value for the end of the range, e.g. B$6.  Otherwise you're going to be looking at cells below your table, which is fine as long as they're empty, but kind of sloppy.

```
Column C:  =IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$6,D1)=0,A1,MINIFS(A2:A$6,B2:B$6,D1))
```

Comment: This is close, but in what I'm looking for, col C should always be equal to or before the date in the same row in col A (i.e. it only considers the rows above it)

Comment: Oops my bad.   I don’t have time to do a proper fix, but I imagine it would be something like doing the bottom one first and then copying upwards to get the references right., and using the absolute $1 for the top of the range.  And probably MAXIFS instead of MINIFS.